# how to make an iframe adjust height to the content

Tags: html, iframe, web, height

I'm building a web page where i need to make different sections and i want the page to adjust height to the section that is beeing viewed in a certain moment.
Which is the best way to achieve this?
I was trying to do it with iframes and target opening

```
    <a href="/example" target="myframe">
```

but i cant make the iframe adjust to the content beeing displayed.

Any help would be aprecciated!
Thanks in advance

What i want is a window to unfold from the bottom of the page whenever someone clicks on "more info".
I thought i could achieve it with an iframe

Comment: i edited my purpose... so maybe someone can suggest a better idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution and it solved my problem perfectly! It even has the option to rezise width.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function setIframeHeight( iframeId ) /** IMPORTANT: All framed documents *must* have a DOCTYPE applied **/
{
var ifDoc, ifRef = document.getElementById( iframeId );

 try
 {   
 ifDoc = ifRef.contentWindow.document.documentElement;  
 }
 catch( e )
 { 
  try
  { 
   ifDoc = ifRef.contentDocument.documentElement;  
  }
  catch(ee)
  {   
  }  
 }

 if( ifDoc )
 {
  ifRef.height = 1;  
  ifRef.height = ifDoc.scrollHeight;

  /* For width resize, enable below.  */

  // ifRef.width = 1;
  // ifRef.width = ifDoc.scrollWidth; 
 }
}

</script>

<iframe id = "myIframe"  onload = "setIframeHeight( this.id )">
```

I found it here: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?747398-IFRAME-Auto-Height

Answer (score 1):

this works in all browsers

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>auto iframe height adjust</title>
<style>
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//
function sizeFrame() {
var F = document.getElementById("myFrame");
if(F.contentDocument) {
 F.height = F.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight+30; //FF 3.0.11, Opera 9.63, and    Chrome
} else {
F.height = F.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+30; //IE6, IE7 and Chrome
}
}
window.onload=sizeFrame;
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

An iframe capable browser is
    required to view this web site.

Comment: It didn't work.. Should i add something to the iframe body tag?

Comment: This is my iframe tag: <iframe style="border:0px;" width="830px" name="myframe" scrolling="no"/>

Comment: add your content page ..also

Comment: what do you mean by adding my content page??

Comment: help please!! i edited my purpose so maybe u can help me with some other suggestion. maybe a link?